# Custom nib UITableViewCell height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I've created a custom UITableViewCell in IB, linked it to the root view controller's property for it, and set it up in CellForRowAtIndexPath. But the height of my drawn cells doesn't match what I setup in IB, advice? Here's some screenshots and the code.
[image]

[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *AddressCellIdentifier = @"AddressCellIdent";

    UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AddressCellIdentifier];
    if (thisCell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AddressCell" owner:self options:nil];
        thisCell = addressCell;
        self.addressCell = nil;
    }

    return thisCell ;
}
```

addressCell is a @property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *addressCell;, and is linked up in IB to the file's owner (the table view controller).

I'm using the example from Apple's table view programming guide.

Comment: Follow this link and get answer to your question - [get row height from NIB file][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18503213/2086991

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust the height of the cell by using:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGFloat result;
    result = 120.0f;
    return result;
}
```

This will work with custom cells.

Comment: Too bad, I knew about heightForRowAtIndexPath but I was hoping that using a NIB based cell would let me avoid having to use it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem and the same question. If we set the height of the cell on IB, why should we set it in heightForRowAtIndexPath as well?

Comment: Apple's example of using custom cells from nib that have various heights also uses a nib based table view that gets loaded by the controller. I'm guessing (haven't tested it) that using [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:] causes the default height to be used instead of the nib's settings.

Comment: Getting the height of the cell itself instead of hard code it should be preferable. The question is how to do that?

Comment: i refactored my table fro prototype cells to nibs, it did work on prototype cells even using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. I've set the height of my nib cells, the cells are now 44points high

Answer (score 7):

There are two places in the IB where you need to set the row height.  First the custom row height for the cell itself.  Click on the cell you want to resize, then click on the Size inspector (ruler) in the Utilities window on the right.  Set your row height at the top under the Table View Cell section.  Click the Custom checkbox.
Then click on your Table View in the Document Outline window on the left.  Go back to the size inspector in Utilities window on the right and set the Row height for the entire table to the desired height.
With this implementation you don't need to add any code to your tableviewcontroller.

Comment: So I set the row height in nib file and also implemeted heightForRowAtIndexPath. Then I spent 1 hour beating my head over why the UI was going crazy. Turns out I needed to set the height in tableView properties as well. Xcode sucks big time. Anyways thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

The [delegate's `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:) is one approach, as WrightsCS says. Another option, if all of the rows will be the same height, is to set the [`rowHeight` property of the table view](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/rowHeight) itself. (The former has the advantage of letting you return arbitrary values for each row.)

Comment: Actually, if you define which cells to change the height, they will not all be the same height, so your wrong in that sense. Your right in the case of my example.

Comment: Huh? That was my point: the delegate method allows the rows to be different. They're not in your example, but they *could* be. Setting the `rowHeight` property doesn't give you that option.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following snippet. Height right from the nib file.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   if (indexPath.row == 0) {
      return self.cell0.contentView.bounds.size.height;
   }
   if (indexPath.row == 1) {
      return self.cell1.contentView.bounds.size.height;
   }
   if (indexPath.row == 2) {
      return self.cell2.contentView.bounds.size.height;
   }

   return 44.0;
}
```

Do not forget to load you cells in - (void)viewDidLoad

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourView" owner:self options:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do when creating the table view to ensure the row height matches the row height defined in the cell's nib:

```
- (UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (_tableView == nil) {
        _tableView = [[UITableView alloc]
                      initWithFrame:self.view.bounds
                      style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        _tableView.dataSource = self;
        _tableView.delegate = self;

        [_tableView
         registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"<CELL NIB NAME>" bundle:nil]
         forCellReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];

        // Get the cell's root view and set the table's 
        // rowHeight to the root cell's height.
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"<CELL NIB NAME>"
                                                     owner:self
                                                   options:nil];
        UIView *cellView = (UIView *)nib[0];
        if (cellView) {
            _tableView.rowHeight = cellView.bounds.size.height;
        }        
    }
    return _tableView;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Elegant and best approach to the problem imho

Answer (score 0):

For people who are still interested in an alternative answer and dont want to implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, good news :).

You can set the row height in de xib like this:

[image]

This is not enough. In fact this will be totally ignored in runtime. The solution is to set the incentric size by setting top and bottom constraints of content of the cell. The content will push the top and bottom of its container which will result in a higher cell :).

[image]