# How do I read a UITableViewCell (subclass)'s height from a NIB?

Tags: ios

I have a UITableViewCell (really a subclass) defined in a NIB.  In the NIB I've set the frame height to 183, I also set the "Row Height" to 183 and ticked off custom.

In my original question stuff all went wrong here.  It looked like I was getting a wrong height back, and the cell loaded at the wrong height and later resized to the right height making a nasty visual glitch.

In reality I was doing some stupid stuff (and always returning the wrong height), and it was too late at night for me to figure it out, so I asked SO for help and went to sleep.   The sleep (+coffee) made everything clear.

So for the record, if you load your custom UITableViewCell from a NIB you can look at frame.size.height and the right number comes back.

If you return the wrong number from `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` you can get this glitch, at least if the errant cell is the last one in the table (I expect the problem will manifest in another way for other cells)

So I've solved my own problem, and hopefully left enough info for anyone else who hits this.  If anyone thinks this ought to have an official answer rest assured I plan on accepting the best looking one in a day or 3.

Comment: The height of the cell loaded from the NIB is good when first loaded, it goes bad somewhat later (I misunderstood what my own logging was telling me).   So I can cache the result (faster then loading a NIB a lot of times anyway!), and I'm good with that.    I still don't understand why the cell gets displayed short and then jumps to tall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First UITableViewDelegate method, which gets called is heightForRowAtIndexPath not the UITableViewDataSource method, cellForRowAtIndexPath.

You can get your custom cell height only in cellForRowAtIndexPath, where you alloc-init that cell. So, it won't consider custom cell height over here.

It will take the height for the cell which is mentioned in heightForRowAtIndexPath method only. As it gets called first.

Answer (score 9):

You can use this example code to get cell height from NIB

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ELConvCurListViewCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0] bounds].size.height;
}
```

**Update:** You can get and assign height of NIB once time in the `viewDidLoad` to the `cellHeight` variable and in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` use `return cellHeight`

Comment: This is really inefficient. You shouldn't do this. It will kill your table scroll performance.

Comment: This is just example. You can get and assign height of NIB once time in the `viewDidLoad` to the `cellHeight` variable and in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` use `return cellHeight`

Comment: I know, but it's a bad example that people might follow. Doing in viewDidLoad like you just suggested would have been a better answer.

Comment: Useful snippet, but consider editing the answer to include your comment!